# Visual studio scaffold nodejs missing all modules?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I used visual studio to create an node express 4 project. However it cannot run and all the entries under npm show (missing). I cannot find the node_modules folder too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't install them automatically.  Either run `npm install` from a command window, or right click on the "npm" item in the project structure and do the install that way.  I would recommend doing it through the command prompt though, if you are on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: VS 2015 is only 32 bit, and some packages (like node-sass) recompile during install.  If the install is being ran through VS, it will compile as a 32 bit package.  If you run it from the command line, that's a 64 bit shell, so it will recompile as a 64 bit package

Comment: Interesting. Right now my development pc is windows 64 bit. But the app will be deployed to a Linux machine. What's the simplest way to deploy it?

Comment: That part I can't answer, I live in an MS world right now, so I've never had to deploy to Linux